# What is the difference between @Scope("session") and @SessionScoped

Tags: jsf, scope

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-integration-example/).

It uses `@Scope("session")` and `@SessionScoped` in different implementations.

What are the differences?

Answer (score 1):

It is actually explained in the tutorial:

> Mixed use of both JSF and Spring annotations are working fine, but it
>   look weird and duplicated – @Component and @ManagedBean together.
>   Actually, you can just uses a single @Component, see following new
>   version, it’s pure Spring, and it works!

So the `@SessionScoped` is the JSF solution. And `@Scope("session")` is the pure Spring solution.

Using the `@SessionScoped` will make your application more portable, when for example you want to switch to Java EE. However using Spring-DI gives you a more consistent implementation.